# Torsocks server failure when running monerod with Tor on Tails

Tags: monerod, blockchain, synchronization, tor

I'm trying to run the Monero daemon (`monerod`) v. 0.12.2.0 **with Tor on Tails 3.7.1**.

I'm doing exactly what is written here: [Medium - Sheep’s Noob guide to Monero GUI in Tails 3.2](https://medium.com/@Electricsheep56/sheeps-noob-guide-to-monero-gui-in-tails-3-2-d75c4e829c17). Basically:

1. Download Monero from [getmonero.org](https://getmonero.org/)
2. Add this rule to iptables: `iptables -I OUTPUT -p tcp -d 127.0.0.1 --dport 18081 -j ACCEPT`
3. Run Monero daemon with the following parameters: `DNS_PUBLIC=tcp TORSOCKS_ALLOW_INBOUND=1 torsocks ./monerod --p2p-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 --no-igd --rpc-bind-ip 127.0.0.1 --data-dir /home/amnesia/Monero/Blockchain`

However, **`monerod` keeps printing this error and doesn't synchronize blocks**:

```
1529169990 ERROR torsocks[27129]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:533)
[1529169990] libunbound[27129:0] error: outgoing tcp: connect: Connection refused for 31.3.135.232
```

Many users seem to encounter this problem:

- [Medium - Sheep’s Noob guide to Monero GUI in Tails 3.2 (comments)](https://medium.com/@diegoms/hi-electric-sheep-first-of-all-thanks-for-your-guide-41c55ac29d23)
- [r/Monero - Monero Daemon over TOR / Tails](https://www.reddit.com/r/Monero/comments/6vfsnu/monero_daemon_over_tor_tails/)

This IP (31.3.135.232) seems to be **one of several default DNS servers for Monero** according to the logs:

```
2018-06-16 17:24:25.173     7c8764b585c0    INFO    global  src/daemon/main.cpp:280 Monero 'Lithium Luna' (v0.12.0.0-master-release)
2018-06-16 17:24:25.173     7c8764b585c0    INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:53    Initializing cryptonote protocol...
2018-06-16 17:24:25.173     7c8764b585c0    INFO    global  src/daemon/protocol.h:58    Cryptonote protocol initialized OK
2018-06-16 17:24:25.174     7c8764b585c0    INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:63 Initializing p2p server...
2018-06-16 17:24:25.174     7c8763776700    WARN    net.dns src/common/dns_utils.cpp:547    Using default public DNS server(s): 194.150.168.168, 81.3.27.54, 31.3.135.232, 80.67.169.40, 209.58.179.186 (TCP)
2018-06-16 17:24:25.174     7c8763776700    INFO    global  src/common/dns_utils.cpp:218    Using public DNS server(s): 194.150.168.168, 81.3.27.54, 31.3.135.232, 80.67.169.40, 209.58.179.186 (TCP)
2018-06-16 17:24:45.175     7c8764b585c0    INFO    global  src/daemon/p2p.h:68 p2p server initialized OK
2018-06-16 17:24:45.175     7c8764b585c0    INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:63 Initializing core RPC server...
2018-06-16 17:24:45.176     7c8764b585c0    INFO    global  contrib/epee/include/net/http_server_impl_base.h:76 Binding on 127.0.0.1:18081
2018-06-16 17:24:45.176     7c8764b585c0    INFO    global  src/daemon/rpc.h:69 core RPC server initialized OK on port: 18081
2018-06-16 17:24:45.176     7c8764b585c0    INFO    global  src/daemon/core.h:86    Initializing core...
2018-06-16 17:24:45.176     7c8764b585c0    INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:427 Loading blockchain from folder /home/amnesia/Cryptocurrencies/Monero/Blockchain/lmdb ...
2018-06-16 17:24:45.197     7c8764b585c0    INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:525 Loading checkpoints
1529169990 ERROR torsocks[27129]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:533)
[1529169990] libunbound[27129:0] error: outgoing tcp: connect: Connection refused for 31.3.135.232
1529169990 ERROR torsocks[27129]: General SOCKS server failure (in socks5_recv_connect_reply() at socks5.c:533)
[1529169990] libunbound[27129:0] error: outgoing tcp: connect: Connection refused for 31.3.135.232
...
```

**Eventually after several minutes/dozens of retries**, it will start synchronizing the blockchain, but I have to wait several minutes each time I start the daemon.

I'm not sure what's the problem here:

- Is it some firewall/Tor misconfiguration?
- Is it a Monero DNS server that is down? If so, why `monerod` keeps retrying on the same server instead of switching to another one (it seems there are at least 5 DNS servers according to the logs)?

Comment: It seems the problem was indeed 31.3.135.232 being down. A few days later it is back online and I'm not experiencing errors anymore.

Comment: Is there a solution? After three years :D